# Does the attack roll bonus of Escalating Assault apply to Virtuous Strike

Tags: dnd-4e

So in a Swordmage/Paladin hybrid scenario:

If during an encounter Escalating Assault were to trigger a MBA and I decide to replace the MBA with a Virtuous Strike, do I recieve the bonus of Escalating Assualt's +1 to future MBA's?

If during the same encounter Escalating Assault were to trigger a second time and I decide to replace the MBA with Virtuous Strike, do I recieve the bonus of Escalating Assualt's +1 to that attack?

The essential parts:

**Escalating Assault:**

```
Each time you make a melee basic attack granted by your Aegis of Assault power, you gain a cumulative +1 bonus on future attack rolls made for the melee basic attacks granted by this power (up to a maximum bonus of +3)
```

**Virtuous Strike**

```
Special: This power can be used as a melee basic attack
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes to both.**

Escalating Assault improves melee basic attacks. Because Virtuous Strike says it can be used *as a* melee basic rather than *in place of a* melee basic, it is an MBA and therefore benefits from Escalating Assault.